# R言語のError: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date onlyエラーを修正する方法について

Tags: r, tidyverse, ggplot2

以下のRコードを実行するとError: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date onlyというメッセージが出てしまいます。
scale_x_date(breaks = time_label, date_labels = "%m/%d")あたりのフォーマットがいけないのかなと推測しているのですが、どの様に修正すれば良いかがわかりません。
教えていただきたいです。
使用しているcsvデータをHTMLに変換したものも載せておきます。
よろしくお願いします。

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(ggrepel)
library(conflicted)

conflict_prefer(name = "filter", winner = "dplyr")

setwd("~/desktop")
data <- read.csv("weight_2020.csv")

data %>%
  filter(!is.na(turn_time)) %>%
  pull(turn_time) -> time_label

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=weight, group=1, label=label, color = 'factor(turn)', size = 'factor(turn)')) +
  geom_line(size=0.3,color='grey50') +
  geom_point() +
  geom_blank(aes(y=0.5)) +
  geom_text_repel(size=5,nudge_y = 0.8, segment.size = 0.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('grey40', 'red3')) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1,3)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = time_label, date_labels = "%m/%d") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background =element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.3, color = "grey92"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(rep(0.5, 4), "cm"),
        title = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "grey50", size = 0.2),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.04, "cm"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11),
        text = element_text(family = "HiraKakuPro-w3"),
        legend.position = "None") +
  labs(y = "体重減少分(kg)") +
  ggtitle('30日間ダイエット(8月20日からの減少分)')
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>time    weight    turn_1kg    turn_time    label</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-20    0    1    2020-08-20    0kg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-21    -0.1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-22    0.2    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-23    0.1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-24    0.1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-25    0.5    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-26    -0.5    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-27    -0.8    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-28    -1.3    1    2020-08-28    -1kg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-29    0.1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-30    1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-08-31    -0.3    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-01    -1.4    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-02    -1.1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-03    -1.3    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-04    -1.2    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-05    -1.5    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-06    -1.8    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-07    -2.1    1    2020-09-07    -2kg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-08    -2.2    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-09    -2.1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-10    -2.6    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-11    -2.5    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-12    -2.7    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-13    -2.1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-14    -3.2    1    2020-09-14    -3kg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-15    -3.1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-16    -3.6    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-17    -3.6    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-18    -4.1    1    2020-09-18    -4kg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-19    -4.1    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-20    -4.2    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-21    -3.9    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-22    -4.4    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-23    -5    1    2020-09-23    -5kg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2020-09-24    -5.2    0    NA    NA</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

これは文字通り, `scale_x_date()` を指定した X軸には `Date` 型の変数しか指定できないということです. csv を HTML に変換したということで, 正確に再現できないのですが, おそらく `read.csv()` を使ったことで `time` と `turn_time` が `factor` 型などで読み込まれてしまっているのではないかと思います. 提示いただいたプログラムでは `tidyverse` を使用しているようなので, 代わりに `read_csv()` を使うと `Date` 型で読み込んでくれるかもしれません. あるいは手動で変換してください. 以下のように:

```r
time_label <- as.Date(time_label, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
data$time <- as.Date(data$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

私の環境ではこれでグラフを描画できました

Comment: 返信遅くなってしまいすみません。
教えていただいた通りに実行したところ、正常に動作してグラフの描画ができました。ありがとうございました。